# Laravel/ Lighthouse GraphQL - how to find by slug attribute?

Tags: laravel, graphql, nuxt.js, vue-apollo, laravel-lighthouse

I'm creating a Laravel backend for a Nuxt app, and am using Lighthouse-PHP to deliver data via GraphQL.

I'm trying to set up a query to do a find by slug instead of the default ID. When I run the query in the graphql playground, it correctly returns the data, however when I load the page on the frontend, it returns `null`.

**Backend**

*schema.graphql*

```
type Query {
  forumCategoryBySlug(slug: String! @eq): ForumCategory @find
}

type ForumCategory {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  slug: String!
  subcategories: [ForumSubcategory!]! @hasMany
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
}
```

*ForumCategory.php model*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class ForumCategory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'slug'
    ];

    public function subcategories(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ForumSubcategory::class);
    }
}
```

**Frontend**

*Index.vue*

```js
import categoryQuery from '~/apollo/queries/forum/category.gql';
export default {
  apollo: {
    category: {
      prefetch: false,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      query: categoryQuery,
      variables () {
        return {
          slug: this.$route.params.slug
        };
      }
    }
  },
}
```

*category.gql*

```
query Category($slug: String!) {
  category: forumCategoryBySlug(slug: $slug) {
    id
    title
    description
    slug
  }
}
```

I feel like I've triple-checked every little thing but can't for the life of me figure out why the data is still returning `null`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: compare network requests (with graphiql/playground), body (value for variable passed properly?), headers, ... auth/ACL reasons?

Comment: I was just doing that actually, and they appear to be identical. I'm messing around with creating a custom resolver (https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/the-basics/fields.html#resolving-fields) right now

Comment: try to recreate request in postman

Comment: It all looks good there. I'm not sure why it's working in the Playground and not in the app, but I have a feeling it has something to do with needing to create a custom Lighthouse resolver.

Comment: not, for sure not a resolver level if it works in playground (still 'external', from FE call) ...middleware/auth/other reasons, check detaily headers/cors/auth

Comment: Hmm good point. I did "fix" a CORS issue earlier, so maybe that actually caused some other issues. I'll have to dig into it, thanks!

Comment: hmm, probably not cors as it wouldn't return normal 200 response, it affects entire response, not fields/query parts

Comment: Also a good point. I’ve been staring at it so long nothing makes sense anymore haha. Somehow both Playground and my app are now returning null so I’m not getting anything back now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after a few days. Essentially I needed to create a custom resolver.

*schema.graphql*

```
type Query {
  forumCategoryBySlug(slug: String! @eq): ForumCategory
}
```

*app/GraphQL/Queries/ForumCategoryBySlug.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;
use App\Models\ForumCategory;

class ForumCategoryBySlug
{
    /**
     * @param  null  $_
     * @param  array<string, mixed>  $args
     */
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        $category = \App\Models\ForumCategory::findBySlug($args["slug"])->first();
        return $category;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but something like this would have been enough

`schoolByCode(code: String! @eq): School @first`